# Were Soviet Union's best trained and equipped forces deployed on the Chinese border and not against NATO?

Tags: soviet-union, china

I heard a scholarly gentleman make this claim (without giving any details of his sources) that after the Sino-Soviet split the most capable forces were not aligned for a war with the West but were deployed against a Chinese threat.

Is there any documented evidence for this?

Comment: Maybe you could specify which time period this would be. All of the 70s and 80s?

Comment: Do you remember the name of the "_scholarly gentleman_"?  Not all 'scholars' are equally reliable as sources.

Comment: [Warsaw Pact Order of Battle June 1989](http://suptg.thisisnotatrueending.com/graveyard/26912082/images/1377961541351.pdf): Group of Soviet Forces Germany, 9 pages; Far East Military District, 2 pages.

Comment: Not really clear enough for an answer. "Most capable forces" could mean a Spetsnaz battalion or a Guards Tank Army; or, given Zhukov's view that 'quantity has a quality of its own', it could just mean numbers.

Comment: It's also a bit subjective. According to the British army the best Soviet army was 3SA, and according to the Americans it was (iirc) 8GTA, i.e. the ones they were facing, respectively.

Comment: Level of training is hard to discern, but best equipped certainly no . Units in the East tended to receive newer equipment after those in the West. For example IS-3M tank still served in Transbaikal Military District in 1980's while units opposing NATO switched to much more modern T-80.

Comment: @sempaiscuba - one might add that not all gentlemen are scholars, and worse, not all scholars are gentlemen *shakes head sadly*